# Start MapsDirectionsTask in walk mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps

In Windows Phone 8, is it possible to call an equivalent of MapsDirectionsTask in walk mode, instead of drive mode? Maybe using some URI sheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: Get HereLaunchers from NuGet and use the DirectionsRouteDestinationTask, which has a RouteMode property.